# Can you reliably check date string equality in python in ISO8601?

Tags: python, string, date

This seems to work, but I don't have enough experience in Python to say "this will always work". Can someone confirm or chime in here with an example that breaks this?

```
ipdb> '2017-01-01' > '2016-12-31'
True
ipdb> '2017-01-01' < '2016-12-31'
False
ipdb> '2017-01-01' >= '2016-12-31'
True
ipdb> '2017-07-01' < '2017-12-31'
True
```

Comment: As long as it's the same format and respects ISO8601, it should work just fine. One of the reasons ISO8601 was formed like that is easy string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

While your method does work in some cases (notably the ones you gave and all like them), it does fail in some corner cases. For example [ISO 8601](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) allows you to give dates in week format, e.g. the first day of week 1 2017 (2:nd of January) can be written "2017-W02-1".

If you try that, you get a problem:

```
>>> '2017-12-31' > '2017-W01-1'
False
```

Although it should be true.

If you truly want support for ISO 8601, you should use an appropriate package, like [`isodate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isodate) (install by `pip install isodate`). Then you can do even those corner cases properly:

```
>>> isodate.parse_date('2017-12-31') > isodate.parse_date('2017-W01-1')
True
```